# Checking deletion and update ui angular ngResource module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, api, ngresource

How can I check what is really happening in the below delete function? Every time I delete it says "Success" but the UI doesn't update .

HTML

```html
<md-content >
  <div id="main" class="well">
    <table cellpadding="20" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(head, value) in models[0]">
          <span>{{head}}</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in models">
        <td ng-repeat="(name, value) in row" ng-scope>
          <span ng-click="" ng-bind="row[name]"></span>
        </td>
        <td >
          <a target="_self" href="#" ng-click="downlaodId(row)">Downlaod</a>
        </td>
        <td >
          <a target="_self" href="#" ng-click="deleteId(row)" confirmation-needed="Really Delete?">Delete</a>
        </td>  
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Controller

```
$scope.deleteId = function (idPassed) {
  fileLoadService.delete({ 'id': idPassed.id }, function(successResult) {
    alert('Deleted');
  }, function (errorResult) {
    // do something on error
    if (errorResult.status === 404) {
      alert('Ooops');
    }
  });
};
```

my UI looks like this after click delete 
fileLoadservice

```
app.factory('fileLoadService', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
      "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/:id",
      { id: "@id" },
      { query: { 'method': 'GET', isArray: true }
    });
 }]);
```

[image]

Comment: you should update your `model` on delete

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from your code:

```
$scope.deleteId = function (idPassed) {

    fileLoadService.delete({ 'id': idPassed.id },function(successResult) {
        alert('Deleted');
    }, function (errorResult) {
```

You are doing nothing to the current model, just sending an alert `Deleted` when you hit the delete button. If you want it to do something else..... you should put that functionality in the code.

For example:

```
$scope.deleteId = function (idPassed) {

        fileLoadService.delete({ 'id': idPassed.id },function(successResult) {
            var index = $scope.models.indexOf(idPassed);
            $scope.models.splice(index, 1);
            alert('Deleted');
        }, function (errorResult) {
```

Comment: What do u mean ? This is a method (deleteId(id)) is called by the button in the UI.  fileLoad service returns resource. What do i miss her

Comment: Your model is never updated. If you want the changes to be reflected on the current screen, you need to update the model. Please check the code I posted above.

Comment: Thanks,it worked on ui but am not sure if the api is working deletion on the api because when I reload the page it just came up. does jsonplaceholder api persist change for a while

Comment: If that's the case, its an issue with your API or possibly the fileLoadService.

Comment: this is the service it is fine loading the api  
app.factory('fileLoadService', ['$resource',
              function ($resource) {
                  return $resource(
         "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/:id",
         { id: "@id" },
         {

             "query": { 'method': 'GET', isArray: true }

         });
     
                  
  }]);